# encodeURL() adding jsessionID when not needed

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, deployment

I am writing a Java Servlet and using Tomcat 8.5.

I want to manage the cookies of the web application. I am facing many problems one of them is the behavior of encodeURL(), the documentation states that the methods return the URL with the jsessionID if the browser doesn't allow cookies or sessions, otherwise it returns the original URL.

Unfortunately the result is that the **encodeURL() is adding the jsessionID every time** (even if the cookies allows it and the jsession id cookie is created).

I have wrote this code:

```
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String origin = request.getHeader("referer");
        String encodedURL = origin;
        encodedURL = response.encodeURL(origin);
        System.out.println("origin: " + origin+ "  encoded: " + encodedURL);
```

That creates a session, retrieves the current URL, use the encodeURL on the URL and then prints the origin link and the one after have used the method.

**As i said there is no case in which encodedURL is equal to origin but this is wrong.**
To get a more detailed view, i am forwarding the control of the page when a button in a jsp page is clicked.